# AJAX post not returning xml data in jQuery 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

While migrating a CTF scoreboard from an older version of jQuery to version 2.0.2, I've noticed that the jQuery post function doesn't appear to retrieve the xml data. The code works fine in 1.8.3 but fails to function in 1.9.1. Is there anyway to fix this without using jQuery migrate?

```
form.submit
(
    function()
    {
        $.post
        (
            'ajax.php?m=login',
            {
                'username': $( '#username' ).attr( 'value' ),
                'password': $( '#password' ).attr( 'value' ),
                'token': token
            },
            function( xml )
            {
                switch( $( xml ).find( 'code' ).text() )
                {
                    case '1':
                        login();
                        clear_mainframe( false );
                        break;

                    case '2':
                        toggle_color( $( '#header' ), 'orange' );
                        break;

                    case '3':
                        toggle_color( $( '#header' ), 'red' );
                        break;
                }
            }
        );

        return false;
    }
);
```

Comment: try passing `'xm'` as the last parameter to `$.post()`

Comment: are there any errors??

Comment: No errors occur. Nothing happens. When I alert the xml data it comes up blank, unlike in version 1.8.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out was was messing up the script. .attr() in newer versions only retrieves the attribute. I changed them to .prop() instead and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell jQuery what type of data is coming back with the 4th parameter to `$.post` (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).  It's possible the heuristics used by jQuery changed.

You should also inspect in a browser (developer toolbar) what the raw response is that is coming back from the server. That will split the difference whether it's an issue with jQuery and how it's parsing the response, or if your server is not even returning XML to begin with.